# Titanium/ Appcelerator Alloy - Closing multiple parent windows

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I have 4 views all with a single button. I want the following simple behaviour.

- **home**: Clicking the button should go to **dashboard**. Clicking the Android back button should exit the application
- **dashboard**: Clicking the button should open **profile**. Clicking the Android back button should close the current window and return back to **home**.
- **profile**: Clicking the button should open **settings**. Clicking the Android back button should close the current window and return back to **dashboard**.
- **settings**: Clicking the button should close the **settings**, **dashboard** and **profile** pages and return the user back to **home**. Clicking the Android back button should close only the current window and return back to **profile**.

This is what I have so far:

**home**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Button onClick="openProfile">Open Dashboard</Button>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

With JS:

```
function openDashboard() {
    Alloy.createController('dashboard').getView(); 
}
```

**dashboard**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Button onClick="openProfile">Open Profile</Button>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

With JS:

```
function openProfile() {
    Alloy.createController('profile').getView(); 
}
```

**profile**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Button onClick="openSettings">Open Settings</Button>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

With JS:

```
function openSettings() {
    Alloy.createController('settings').getView(); 
}
```

**settings**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Button onClick="backToHome">Back To Home</Button>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

However I am unsure on the JS to use to close both parent windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 best ways to do this:

**Method 1: Using JS-only event dispatcher system.**

Create and put a file **'EventDispatcher.js'** in *app-lib* folder and put this code in it.

```
module.exports = _.clone(Backbone.Events)
```

Put this code in dashboard.js & profile.js

```
var eventsDispatcher = require('EventDispatcher');
eventsDispatcher.on('closeEventFromSettings', closeMethod);

function closeMethod() {
    eventsDispatcher.off('closeEventFromSettings', closeMethod);
    $.getView().close();
}
```

Finally use this code on settings.js whenever you want to close dashboard and profile windows

```
require('EventDispatcher').trigger('closeEventFromSettings');
```

**Method 2: Passing callbacks to window controller.**

**dashboard.js**

```
function closeMe() {
    $.dashboard.close();
}

function openProfile() {
    Alloy.createController('profile', {cb: closeMe}).getView(); 
}
```

**profile.js**

```
function closeMe() {
    $.args.cb();    // it will close the dashboard
    $.profile.close();
}

function openSettings() {
    Alloy.createController('settings', {cb: closeMe}).getView(); 
}
```

**settings.js**

```
function backToHome() {
    $.args.cb();
}
```

There are other ways obviously, but I prefer to use these 2 only from performance and maintenance perspective.

Comment: what do you think about my way? I also edited your answer to remove those images.

Comment: this is the same thing, you can pass anything as callback ... either the whole controller reference or an array or whatever you like, but the logic is to pass something into it..

Comment: Also tell me the reason why my answer was not considering those images codes and throwing errors for me. I could not find any valid reason for this from Stack Overflow.

Comment: No idea! If the problem persists try meta stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to do it is by passing the parent windows across like so:

**home**

```
function openDashboard() {
    Alloy.createController('dashboard', {'parent': $}).getView(); 
}
```

**dashboard**

```
function openProfile() {
    Alloy.createController('profile', {'parent': $}).getView(); 
}
```

**profile**

```
function openSettings() {
    Alloy.createController('settings', {'parent': $}).getView(); 
}
```

**settings**

```
function backToHome() {
     $.getView().close(); // Close current window
     $.args.parent.getView().close(); // Close profile window
     $.args.parent.args.parent.getView().close(); // Close dashboard
}
```

Loops can make the above code more readable like so:

```
function backToHome() {   
     var controller = $;
     for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         controller.getView().close();
         controller = controller.args.parent;
     }
}
```